# Gecko/Firefox 44.0.2 blocks Google fonts

Tags: css, .htaccess, firefox, fonts, cors

Soon after the release of the most recent Gecko, Firefox and all browsers based on it (including Droid app browsers like AdBlock) ceased to render my Google fonts at my site. No other browsers were affected.

Viewing my site using the developer's tools in Firefox (44.0.2), the following message is displayed for one the fonts:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
>   the remote resource at
>   http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v13/MTP_ySUJH_bn48VBG8sNShampu5_7CjHW5spxoeN3Vs.woff2.
>   (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).

The other fonts have identically written error messages.

I have always allowed for CORS in my .htaccess file with this directive, and it's working for all other browsers:

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

The @font-face rule I use that pertains the font referenced in the error message is:

```
@font-face{font-family:'Bold';font-weight:600;font-style:normal;src:url('http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v13/MTP_ySUJH_bn48VBG8sNSnZ2MAKAc2x4R1uOSeegc5U.eot');src:url('http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v13/MTP_ySUJH_bn48VBG8sNSnZ2MAKAc2x4R1uOSeegc5U.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
local('Open Sans Semibold'),
local('Open-Sans-600'),
url('http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v13/MTP_ySUJH_bn48VBG8sNShampu5_7CjHW5spxoeN3Vs.woff2') format('woff2'),
url('http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v13/MTP_ySUJH_bn48VBG8sNSqRDOzjiPcYnFooOUGCOsRk.woff') format('woff'),
url('http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v13/MTP_ySUJH_bn48VBG8sNSonF5uFdDttMLvmWuJdhhgs.ttf') format('truetype'),
url('http://fonts.gstatic.com/l/font?kit=MTP_ySUJH_bn48VBG8sNSllIn5tFQcqMuf-jhyJP0ps#OpenSans') format('svg');}
```

What has changed in Gecko 44.0.2 that is preventing Google fonts from loading in Firefox and other browsers built on the same code base? And what can be done to fix the problem?

Comment: I'm experiencing different CORS issues with Firefox 44.0.2 clients. This link points to the likely security fix that has caused the issue:

https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/security/advisories/mfsa2016-13/

I do not have a resolution yet.

Comment: Tried to recreate test case based on the snippet above http://jsbin.com/royolabaxo/1 . Firefox does not produce error you are referring. Are you using the JS library on your page or add-on that might parse CSS and trying to fetch the fonts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `https` instead of `http` fixed the problem for me

Answer (score 2):

I also began experiencing this issue with Firefox 44.0.2 (64-bit Windows version) today. I was including the Google fonts on my page like so:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans|Open+Sans+Condensed:700" />
```

I simply did as Iain H. suggested and added the `https:` which fixed the issue.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans|Open+Sans+Condensed:700" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Using CORS to allow access to things on your own server has no effect on things requested from *other* servers, like those fonts.  The server you're requesting from has to send the headers.

That said, I'm not sure what might have changed in Firefox 44.  Firefox has always enforced the same-origin restriction (liftable via CORS), so if it worked before it should ideally continue to work. Submit a bug to Mozilla?